# R Visualization of nested cross-sections for linear regression with categorical variables and interaction terms

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, linear-regression, lattice

I am using R and the lm function to fit a multiple linear regression that uses continuous and categorical determinate variables, as well as interactions between some of these variables.

To visualize the resulting model I have been using the visreg package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/visreg/index.html). This package allows what the reference manual describes as 'cross-section' plots to separately plot responses by a categorical variable, via the optional 'by' argument. It also allows an overlay option to overlay the plots of these categorical responses into one plot (see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/visreg/visreg.pdf and https://web.as.uky.edu/statistics/users/pbreheny/publications/visreg.pdf).

The three key variables I am dealing with are stomatal conductance (continuous dependent variable), water deficit (continuous independent variable), and tree species and leaf age (independent categorical variables). There are interaction terms between all three of these independent variables.

The visreg package easily allows me to plot a cross section for the effect of water deficit on gs by species, to do the same by age, as well as the option to overlay on the same plot (see below).

***Plot 1: gs response to water deficit by species:***
[image: Plot 1: gs response to water deficit by species]

***Plot 2: gs response to water deficit by leaf age:***
[image: Plot 2: gs response to water deficit by leaf age]

***Plot 3: gs response to water deficit by leaf age, overlay on single plot:***
[image: Plot 3: gs response to water deficit by leaf age, overlay on single plot]

However, I need to do something slightly more complex. I need to do a sub-cross-section of a cross-section. In other words, I would like to plot the effect of leaf age on water deficit as in Plot 3, but by each species. So for each species there would be a separate plot showing the interaction of water deficit and leaf age, with the leaf age effects ("o" and "m") overlaid for each species.

Is this possible with the visreg package? If not, what might be other approaches in R to visualizing the model in this way?

Comment: Those are `lattice` graphics, not `ggplot2`. I will edit the tag.

Comment: Thanks! Although I think the package has some ggplot2 functionality as well... https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2017/RJ-2017-046/RJ-2017-046.pdf

Comment: Actually, in section *Cross-sectional plots* it says *The
visreg
package creates cross-sectional plots using, by default, the
lattice
package (Sarkar,
2008).* And in the CRAN index that it imports `lattice`.

Comment: I know. I'm just noting that there is apparently also ggplot2 functionality. http://pbreheny.github.io/visreg/gg.html

Comment: OK, thanks, I hadn't noticed that. would reedit the tag but the 5 tags limit was already reached. Considering that the graphs in the question are `lattice` graphs, do you want `lattice` or `ggplot2`?

Comment: Hmm... Maybe it makes more sense to delete the "interaction" tag and replace with ggplot? Plotting is much more central to this post than the specifics of the statistics...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not currently implemented in `visreg`; you could do something like this as a workaround, but it's not ideal:

```r
library(visreg)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
airquality$Rad <- cut(airquality$Solar.R, 3, labels=c('Low', 'Medium', 'High'))
fit <- lm(Ozone ~ Wind*Temp*Rad, airquality)
mf <- model.frame(fit)
v1 <- subset(visreg(fit, 'Wind', 'Temp', cond=list(Rad='Low'), plot=FALSE), mf$Rad == 'Low')
v2 <- subset(visreg(fit, 'Wind', 'Temp', cond=list(Rad='Medium'), plot=FALSE), mf$Rad == 'Medium')
v3 <- subset(visreg(fit, 'Wind', 'Temp', cond=list(Rad='High'), plot=FALSE), mf$Rad == 'High')
grid.arrange(plot(v1, gg=TRUE) + ggtitle("Solar Radiation: Low"),
             plot(v2, gg=TRUE) + ggtitle("Solar Radiation: Medium"),
             plot(v3, gg=TRUE) + ggtitle("Solar Radiation: High"))
```

[image]

I agree that this would be a nice improvement to `visreg`, though -- I've opened an issue for it [here](https://github.com/pbreheny/visreg/issues/62); hope to get to it when the semester ends.

Comment: This worked, just one issue I'm wondering if you have any suggestion to resolve.

The plot for each species/leaf age combination shows the fit against all corresponding leaf-age data points, rather than just the leaf-age data points that correspond to the species in question. Any thoughts on how to specify for only the data points corresponding to the "species" filter (i.e. whatever specified by the "cond" argument) to show up as points in the corresponding plot?

Comment: Also, would it somehow be possible to use the "overlay" argument for each species, for just one plot per species?

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but why not just do this in ggplot directly?

> to plot the effect of leaf age on water deficit as in Plot 3, but by each species. So for each species there would be a separate plot showing the interaction of water deficit and leaf age, with the leaf age effects ("o" and "m") overlaid for each species

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = CWD_mm,
                 y = ln_gs,
                 color = leaf_age)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
    facet_wrap(~ species)
```

Comment: The problem with that approach is that it will only give me the effect from linear regression with just ln_gs as the dependent variable, and leaf age as the independent variable. But the full multiple linear regression I'm using is actually something closer to ln_gs ~ Leaf_Age + species + water_deficit + time_of_day + day_of_year + time_of_day:water_deficit + Leaf_Age:water_deficit + Leaf_Age:day_of_year+species:water_deficit.

Comment: So with so many variables and interactions, plotting separate gs/leaf_age regressions by species doesn't give me an idea of the effects in the full model. The visreg package does, it just doesn't have the "nested within nested" functionality I'm looking for.